# Write a program to find length of longest consecutive sequence in array of integers?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

For example,
Given [100, 4, 200, 1, 3, 2],
The longest consecutive elements sequence is [1, 2, 3, 4].

```
 public class Array {
  public static void main(String args[]){

    int a[]={10,15,1,2,3,4,5,11,12};

    int b=1;
    int c=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++){

       if(a[i]-a[i+1]==-1){

         b=b+1;
         c=c+1;
         if(b>=c)
       {

       System.out.println(a[i]);

         }
         else{
             b=0;
         } 

    }

}
}
}
```

But i am getting output as 1 2 3 4 11
whereas the output should be 1 2 3 4 5.

How to get the required output,whats the mistake in a code?

Comment: Have you considered sorting the array first?

Comment: you have to sort the array first using the Array class `Array.sort(a);`or you can create a for loop using bubble algorithm

Comment: please, format your code. It is painful to read.

Comment: @davidxxx,edited the code.Hope it is readable.Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
int[] array = {10,15,1,2,3,4,5,11,12};
List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<>(); // prepare temp list for later use
List<List<Integer>> arrays = new ArrayList<>(); // used to store the sequences
int lastNum = array[0]; // get the fist number for compasion in loop
tempList.add(lastNum);
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i]-1 == lastNum) { // check for sequence (e.g fist num was 12,
      // current number is 13, so 13-1 = 12, 
      // so it has the sequence), then store the number
        tempList.add(array[i]); // store it to the temp list
        lastNum = array[i]; // keep current number for the next
    } else { // if it has not the sequence, start the new sequence
        arrays.add(tempList); // fist store the last sequence
        tempList = new ArrayList() // clear for the next sequence
        lastNum = array[i]; // init the lastNumnber
        tempList.add(lastNum);
    }
}
// now iterate for the longest array
// craete an empty array to store the longest
List<Integer> longestLength = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<Integer> arr : arrays) {
    if (arr.size() > longestLength.size()) {
        // check if the current array hase the longest size than the last one
        // if yes, update the last one
        longestLength = arr;
    }
}
// at the end print the result.
System.out.println("longestLength = " + longestLength);
```

**The Result:**

```
longestLength = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: actually i am not getting your logic

Comment: @SainathPawar now the logic may be clear for you! check it!

Comment: Wrong answer. You dont have to sort the array, subsequence are found in unsorted array

Comment: @SainathPawar Try to run it on {4,3,6,5,1,9,6}

Comment: @Tanuj Yadav The sort is indeed an error but the remains is correct.

Comment: @TanujYadav Yeah you are right, here the sort condition optional, if needed you can sort else leave it as it is, but the rest logic is just fine for such requirement. TNX

Comment: "here the sort condition optional". No the sort produces a wrong result according to the OP question.

Comment: @davidxxx OK, Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
public class Array {
      public static void main(String args[]){

        int a[]={10,15,1,2,3,4,5,11,12};

        int ms=0;                  // starting point of max subseq
        int me=0;                   //ending point of max subseq
        int cs=0,ce=0;              //starting and ending  point of current subseq
        int max=0,c=0;           // length of max and current subseq
        for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++){

           if(a[i]-a[i+1]==-1){

             if(c==0)             //we found the first element of a subseq
             {
               cs=i;ce=i+1;c=2;   //made the starting of currrent seq=i, end=i+1 and length=2
              }
             else             // element is a part of subsequence but not first elem
              {
               ce=i+1;c++;     // increased current ending point
              } 

              if(c>max)          // if lenth of current subseq is now largest then update staring and ending points of max
               {
                   max=c;
                   ms=cs;
                   me=ce;
               }
             }
             else             // subseq ended
             {
             cs=0;
             ce=0;
             c=0;
              }
      }
        for(i=ms;i<=me;i++)           //printing max subsequence
         System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
    }
```

**Note: see comments for description**

Comment: will you please explain your logic..it would be great help

Comment: ya sure, wait a min

Comment: ,how did you develop this logic,please suggest me some text books or websites to make logic stronger

Comment: @SainathPawar you need to practice more.

Comment: any text books or website for practising

Comment: @SainathPawar there r no particular books or websites, particulary for subsequence. You must participate in online coding competitions on codechef, hackerearth, etc. And the answer accepted by you is incorrect

Comment: Good answer too that is a little wasted by variable names that are not very meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if you sort the array first. Have you tried that?

Comment: its an array not an arraylist

Comment: you can still sort it

import java.util.array

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
    Arrays.sort(a);
```

then

```
    if(a[i]+1==a[i+1])
          //print it 
     else
        {
            System.out.print(a[i]);
            i=a.length;
        }//stop the loop
```

Comment: if i use the solution provided by you i am getting output as 1 2 3 4...whereas output  needed is 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: just add System.out.print(a[i]); in the else statement to include the last i because you ended the loop in the last a[i]+1 will be 6 so it is not equal to 10 then in else include the last sequential integer

Comment: that will work only in this case, not in general case

Comment: @TanujYadav you can try it in any other primitive int I have edited my answer for clearer info

Comment: suppose you have a subsequence of length 3 and then a subsequence of length 6, then you wont print the largest one

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int a[]={10,15,1,2,3,4,5,11,12};
        Arrays.sort(a);
        ArrayList<Integer>output = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer>temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i =1; i<a.length; i++){
            //If elements have difference of one, add them to temp Arraylist
            if(a[i-1] + 1 == a[i]){
                temp.add(a[i-1]);
            }
            else{
                //Add the last consecutive element 
                temp.add(a[i-1]);

                //If temp is lager then output
                if(temp.size() > output.size()){
                    output = (ArrayList<Integer>) temp.clone();
                        temp.clear();
                }           
            }
        }

        //Outside for loop, making sure the output is the longer list. This is to handle the case where the consecutive sequence is towards the end of the array
        if(temp.size() > output.size()){
            output = (ArrayList<Integer>) temp.clone();System.out.println("after clone outside for " + output.toString());
        }   
        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: ,it gives o/p as 15 1 2 3 4 5.we require 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: I am getting [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] as the output. What is the input you are testing with?